# Parsing different data types in a CSV file in C++?

Tags: c++, csv

I've been searching for hours did as much research as I could and am still struggling with what should be the very simple beginning of the program. I want to parse an inputted file that looks something like this:

53300120483,tyc,593,234

23142443234,bds,32,12

.

.(etc)

.

Right now, I am just trying to get those 4 things for each line and store each of them inside an appropriate variable. Right now I am only writing code to read that very first line, and once I get that working well I will apply it over each line, probably using some sort of while(peek !=EOF)... So far I am using this:

```
string data;
int num1;
string
int num2;
int num3;
string one,three,four;

ifstream inputed;
inputed.open("inputfile.csv");
getline(inputed,data);
stringstream lineStream(data);
getline(lineStream,one,',');
num1 = stoul(one);
getline(lineStream,symb,',');
getline(lineStream,three,',');
num2 = stoi(three);
getline(lineStream,four,',');
num3 = stoi(four);
inputed.close();
cout << num1 << endl;
cout << symb << endl;
cout << num2 << endl;
cout << num3 << endl;
```

right now my output works for symb, num2, num3, however, my num1 turns into this random negative number... example:

input:
45300052593,hws,38,125

output:
-1944587663
hws
38
125

I tried stoul(one), stoi(one), stol(one) but to no avail... Any advice on the reason why my first number becomes this random negative number? I'm guessing theres some kind of overflow into the negatives but I am not sure. As for parsing different data types in a CSV file, would this be a good way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number 45300052593 is too large for a 32bit `int`.
Don't use `int`, but a 64bit type like `int64_t`, `long long` etc.

> I tried stoul(one), stoi(one), stol(one) but to no avail

As long as you store the result in `int`, no variant will help.

Comment: I feel dumb. Thank you. Is my approach with the consecutive getline statements efficient enough? Is that more or less the best approach?

Comment: @hundred_dolla_tea There are many ways with advantages and siadvantages, no single one the "best". Depends on the data, the amount of data, if some old code exists which can be reused with minimal changes, what functions and classes the programmer knows best, etc.etc.  If you like this way, it's ok.

Comment: Using `getline` is fine, but I would probably write something that reads a whole line, and then parses things like `"` and `'`, so you can have `123,"Hello, World!",5.1987` in your input, and get three, not four values. I wouldn't worry too much about performance. If there is A LOT of data, it would be most important to optimise the disk-reads, not how you parse it. And if it's not a lot of data, it's probably quick enough anyway.